# Wordpress - Image containers too large

Tags: css, woocommerce

We asked our web developers to make the images on all the pages as large as possible (Home page, Category page, etc) . This worked really well on those pages where there are 3 images across - they are now nice and large.

The problem is the image that displays on the single image page is now HUGE.. and you have to scroll down to see the thumbnails for the other images.

Apparently they increased the container sizes to do this - I want to leave the images on the home page and category pages alone because they look great, but how do I change the size of the main image on the single product page so it's not quite so huge now?

The url is https://flowersforeveryone.feedmybeta.com/

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within WordPress, the **body_class** function adds unique classes to the  tag for each page/psot/custom post type. This allows you to target specific pages such as a single product page you mention.

In your case, this CSS would reduce the relative image width and then proportional height.

```
.single-product.woocommerce .content-area {
  margin-top: 2.1rem;
 }
 .single-product.woocommerce div.product div.images.woocommerce-product-gallery {
  width: 40%;
  margin: -2.1rem auto 0 auto;
}
```

Thanks

Edited: Updated the CSS to your below comment requirement.

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/

Comment: oh brilliant!! Thank you!!! How do I centre it a bit more now and also bring it up a little higher? (without messing with the responsiveness) Thanks so much!

Comment: `.single-product.woocommerce .content-area {
    margin-top: 2.1rem;
}
.single-product.woocommerce div.product div.images.woocommerce-product-gallery {
    width: 40%;
    margin: -2.1rem auto 0 auto;
}`

Comment: you're a genius! Thank you!! Just out of interest - what does the -2.1rem refer to with the margin? Thanks again!!

Comment: Glad to help you. The negative margin you refer to, moves the flower image container up as requested.

Comment: Cool thanks! I can see the changes I made.. but my friend says she sees the image smaller for a second and then it jumps larger. We've both cleared our cache.. what might be causing this?

Comment: I'd need you to add the CSS to the site to see the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.. with the character count?.. It won't let me paste the entire CSS... ?

Comment: I mean add the CSS to your website. Thanks

Comment: I added the CSS you provided earlier, to my custom.css page.. sorry i'm confused :(

Comment: It does not look to be loading. Are you adding it to the CSS plugin I mentioned yesterday or to custom.scss?

Comment: no i didn't think i needed the plugin.. I'm just adding everything to custom.css, under theme files.